# Is there an API for Chrome print functionality

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm want to use client-side printing to print multiple documents but want some more control over the print functionality or print dialog. This is not possible in IE but I noticed that chrome browser has it own print dialog compared to the default windows print dialog.

Is there an API for the chrome print that I could use in JavaScript?

Comment: An API for a plugin/browser extension or an API available to the web page? The latter does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantly, at the current moment, it is not possible to modify or interact with the browser's print dialog. The one thing you can do is change CSS when printing by adding a @print directive.
For example(html):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

CSS:

```
.noprint{
    display: none;
}
```

This would make all elements with class "noprint" to be invisible when printing the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Printing client-side through the browser is limited by the fact that you don't have greater control over the print dialog. This makes it even more difficult to try and print multiple documents without calling the print dialog multiple times.

Having done some further research the Chrome print dialog does not have any API allowing a developer to hook into. This is a Netscape plugin and was developed in C++ and the extension is only available for Chrome. Internet Explorer dropped Netscape plugins some time ago and there is no equivalent, only ActiveX controls can be used to develop this type of feature in IE.

The CSS is only useful when you want to control what content is actually printed. i.e. a printer friendly version of the html the user is seeing in the browser window.